# Cron output to file immediately

Tags: cron, logs

I have a Python program that runs for several hours at a time, and is run by cron:

```py
import time
for _ in range(1000):
        print(f'{time.strftime("%r", time.localtime())}')
        time.sleep(5)
```

I want cron to write the output to a file as it receives it, so the file always has an updated version of the output. How would I do this?

Comment: Does `print(f'{time.strftime("%r", time.localtime())}', flush=True)` work? If not, post what your crontab entry looks like.

Comment: yup, thanks. is there a way to do it from outside the .py file?

Comment: Perhaps the [`unbuffer` command](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html)?

Comment: `cron` has nothing to do with how the process it has launched will handle its files. Once it gets a match on the date/time columns, it sends the rest of the command to a shell. What is does do is collect any leaked (non-redirected) stdout and stderr, and (by default) mail it to the user's Linux account when the process exits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
* * * * * /home/myuser/myscript.py >> /home/myuser/myscript.log 2>&1
```